# vscode IntelliSense not working correctly with overloaded functions in typescript

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, intellisense, overloading

I have a overloaded function that should accept both object and string/value as follow:

```
type CssRuleNames = 'display' | 'opacity' | 'visibility' | 'z-index';
type CssRulesKeys = { [k in CssRuleNames]?: any };

function add(rule: CssRulesKeys): void;
function add(rule: CssRuleNames, value?: any): void;
function add(rule: CssRulesKeys | CssRuleNames, value?: any) {
  return;
}
```

it won't give me any error and accepts both object and string/value as intended, however, for some reason, the IntelliSense won't work when passing an object and using single/double quote:

[image]

obviously, it is not a big deal, I am just curious why is not working!

Comment: Typescript/javascript don't support method overloading since JS doesn't do type checking on its arguments or even check the number of them.  In general, to achieve something like this, you'll have to do some checking at runtime to figure out what the method should do.  More on this in JS: https://medium.com/@kevinkreuzer/typescript-method-overloading-c256dd63245a.

Comment: @Ben thanks for the comment, I understand that I have to do type checking at runtime, my question is about IntelliSense of overloaded methods, I think the title is misleading, I will change it to make more sense.

Comment: I think that what would happen here is that each successive definition of `add` is overwriting the prior definition.  So, for code completion, it will probably ignore all the previous definitions, since they won't exist later on.

Comment: Have you managed to find a solution on how to resolve this?

Comment: Unfortunately no, I couldn't find any solution for this.